# Cannot access any service through Sql Server 2008 Configuration Manager

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have SQL Server 2008 installed locally on Windows 7, The Configuration Manager starts ok but gives me the error "The server threw an exception. [0x80010105]". I have tried running the manager as administrator to no avail. Anybody any ideas? Cheers.

Comment: Do you see the services in config manager?

Answer (score 1):

I had to install SQL Server 2008 SP1 to fix this problem. I guess it is an issue running on Windows 7 or the fact I also have SQL Server 2005 on this machine.

Comment: In fact, when you install SQL Server on Windows 7, it brings up a huge "THIS PROGRAM IS INCOMPATIBLE" dialogue and insists that you need to install SP1 (or SP3 for 2005) before SQL Server will work

Comment: I upgraded my machine from Vista, where I already had SQL Server 2008 installed. Cheers for your comment though.